# Api request IOS using flurry api

Tags: ios, swift, flurry, flurry-analytics

I have the following code that makes an API request to a flurry.com API endpoint and decodes the request.

```
let url = URL(string: bookStarRateDomainUrl)!

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in
  if let error = error {
    print("Error with fetching book star rates: \(error)")
    return
  }
  
  guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
        (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
    print("Error with the response, unexpected status code: \(response)")
    return
  }

  if let data = data,
    let flurryItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode(FlurryItem.self, from: data) {
    completionHandler(flurryItems.results ?? [])
  }
})
task.resume()
```

The problem is that I cannot use .decode(FlurryItem.self, because the values I get back from the API endpoint is this:

```
[{
     dateTime:2020-06-05 00:00:00.000-07:00
     event|name:BookStarRate
     paramName|name:bookId
     paramValue|name:why-buddism-is-true
     count:3
}]
```

notice how the variable name is "paramName|name". The | makes it impossible to name a variable for that item. What can I do instead?

Comment: Avoid using `try?` as `try catch` block will help debug the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- You need to use enum

```
struct Root: Codable { 
    var date: String
    var name: String  
    var id: Int
    var value: String
    var count: Int
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date = "dateTime" 
        case name = "event|name" 
        case id = "paramName|name" 
        case value = "paramValue|name" 
        case count  
    }
}
```

2- You should use `[FlurryItem].self`

```
let flurryItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([FlurryItem].self, from: data)
```

Comment: This is not what I'm saying at all. The decode line works perfectly fine. The problem is that the key names have a | in them

Comment: look to point 1 and your decode won't work as `[{}]` is an array json  while you decode a dictionary

Comment: how does the FlurryItem object class look? Can you show me example?